# CKAN Datastore Create does not work,action/datastore_create says "Internal Error"

Tags: ckan

"http://MY_CKAN_URL//api/3/action/datastore_create" from API it returnes this error:

```
{
"help": "http://MY_CKAN_URL/api/3/action/help_show?name=datastore_create",
"success": false,
"error": {
"message": "Internal Server Error",
"__type": "Internal Server Error"
}
}
```

I have installed CKAN in Docker and I have the same error and this is what I have inside ckan_default.error.log:

```
[wsgi:error] [pid 20:tid 140290595436288] [remote 127.0.0.1:50840] [SQL: 'CREATETRIGGER zfulltext\n BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON "c8ad5ab0-da25-4935-8619-167ea686a1cf"\n FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE populate_full_text_trigger()']
```

And this inside error.log: [core:notice] [pid 18:tid 140290744224704] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2 -D FOREGROUND'

In Datapusher:
JobError: CKAN DataStore bad response. Status code: 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR. At: http://MY_CKAN_URL/api/3/action/datastore_create. Response: {u'error': {u'__type': u'Internal Server Error', u'message': u'Internal Server Error'},

u'help': u'http://MY_CKAN_URL/api/3/action/help_show?name=datastore_create', u'success': False}

Furthermore, I have this error too:

```
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 10.0.4.222. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit /etc/ckan/default/production.ini
ckan.site_url = http://ckan28.local

And in the Postgres database:
sudo -u postgres createuser -S -D -R -P -l datastore_default
enter password for new role
sudo -u postgres createdb -O ckan_default datastore_default -E utf-8

With sudo -u postgres psql -l
You should have this:
Name                      Owner
datastore_default     ckan_default

Edit:
sudo nano /etc/ckan/default/production.ini

ckan.datastore.write_url = postgresql://ckan_default:ckan_default@localhost/datastore_default
ckan.datastore.read_url = postgresql://datastore_default:datastore_default@localhost/datastore_default

With this it should work fine.